# Imitating Control Groups using AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am aware of the fact that there is no built-in functionality for control groups in the Marketing Cloud.

The workaround I thought of was to apply the control group in an SQL Activity in the Automation Studio i.e. only send to 95% of the rows in the Data Extension. But then we have to send the base Data Extension (the one containing 100% of rows) to the data analyst as well (since they don't log in MC to look at the numbers). This manual approach is doable but far from optimal.

In another forum, somebody recommended that I look into AMPScript to get that functionality. So I am wondering how to apply that there in the email personalization logic?

Should we have an extra column dedicated to this in the Data Extension (e.g. A boolean column like IsControlfGroup)? Please keep in mind that, the person who is looking at the data needs to be aware of who was and was not in the control group at the time of send. Looking at Tracking Extracts, we only get the data about those we send the email to, whereas the ones in Control Group never received the email to being with.

Answer (score 2):

If you had a control group attribute/column in every send context, you could exclude sends to these subscribers using an Exclusion Script like this:

```
AttributeValue("IsControlfGroup") == 1
```

or

```
@IsControlfGroup == 1
```

The NotSent Tracking Extract will give you the exclusions, but it's not readily available.

Reference:

- [**Exclude Subscribers from a Triggered or User-Initiated Send in Marketing Cloud**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339899&type=1&language=en_US&mode=1)
- [**Exclusion Scripts Syntax**](https://ampscript.guide/exclusion-scripts-syntax/)
- [**Report on 'Not Sent' contacts through Journey Builder Emails**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313980&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. SItting tight with another project will come back this asap.

Comment: Hi Adam! The Ampscript Guide's examples require a login which I do not have. But if I've understood your point, you add an `IsControlGroup` column to your Data Extension and populate the values using an SQL Query, then in the AMPScript of the email, we apply the exclusion as you mentioned above. And one should also enable the **NotSent** tracking extracts for the account. Is that correct?

Comment: If my above comment is correct, how do we differentiate between a NotSent row that is due to being in the control group and a NotSent row that has another reason? How will those in the control group look like?