# Exclusion List field in Mobile Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, marketingcloudapi

I have a customer's requirement to get the value of Exclusion List field in MobileConnect send, to do an automatic extraction of control group.

[image: Exclusion List in Mobile Connect]

Does anyone know if it's possible? I've been talking with some SFMC professionals and they said this is not possible.

I've been trying to get this through REST API - I even found the route [POST /sms/v1/messageList/{id}/send](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageList.htm) that has ExclusionListId as one of its parameters, but it seems there isn't a GET route to receive this info specifically.

I'm trying to get this string automatically to use it in a SSJS script, that in the end will do a data extract of the matching DE name.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to SF support team: "I understand that this is important to you, however this feature is currently not available on Salesforce Marketing Cloud.
We appreciate the idea that you have shared and would recommend you to post it on Salesforce's IdeaExchange portal."

I think I'll try to change the approach, as this Adam Spriggs suggestion: [Imitating Control Groups using AMPScript?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291706/imitating-control-groups-using-ampscript)